# deploying app using ClientDataSet

Tags: deploying

I am currently in the process of doing a re-write on a large app of mine from BCB6 using paradox tables, and have started on several of my forms that use DBGrids.  I have already done a conversion of the data from paradox to SQLite 3.

The data in the grids are fine on my development machine (Windows 8 32bit), but when I want to put the app on to a secondary machine (being a WinXP 32bit system) it doesn't want to work when I try and open those forms that have grids on them.  I have isolated the problem to my ClientDataSet not allowing to become Active.  I am building a self contained EXE file for this app, and I have also tried putting several files that I think I may need in to the same fold as my application.  Yes I do have a dbxconnections.ini & a dbxdrivers.ini file in the folder as well.  I am using XE4.

The AV error that I am getting is Access violation at address 007EFA8F in module 'AC.exe'. Read of address 00000000

I am doing a test when I am opening the ClientDataSet

```
try
{
    cdsLots->Avtive = true;  // cdsLots being the ClientDataSet
}
catch (Exception &exception)
{
   ShowMessage("Failing to Open cdsLots");
   Application->ShowException(&exception);
}
```